# Magento 2 free downloadable product order status closed automatically

Tags: magento2, downloadable

I have free downloadable products on my Magento 2 shop (Magento 2.3.4, Migrated from Magneto 1). If a customer purchases this free downloadable product, he gets a zero subtotal order which I set to status processing via Magento Payment settings automatically. The order is also invoiced automatically, but the order always has status "closed" automatically with a correctly cerated invoice and so the download is not working. There is no credit memo created! This should be the only way to get to the status closed according to the Magento Status scheme.

This behavior was not observed in Magento 1, there it was always ending with status "complete" and the download was enabled automatically.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I just found out this behavior is a known bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has published a quality patch which solves the issue, can be installed via composer:

```
composer require magento/quality-patches
./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply MDVA-28656
```

The patch is compatible to Magento 2.3.1-2.3.5 and 2.4.0 so I guess the patch is included in newer versions of Magento2.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25177#issuecomment-711466980

Comment: just confirming, is it about this problem - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328289/downloadable-product-order-status-showing-pending

Comment: Yes, thats the issue I raised here in April 2020. See the fix above, I have not tested it as I removed all free downloads from the shop and converted them to purchase free direct downloads.